# Can use a subquery to assign LIMIT value in a MySql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, limit

I need extract de last rows of a table without no order.
I Try this but don't function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contabilidad.emp001_series
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)-10 AS TOTAL FROM contabilidad.emp001_series)
```

I need the result in natural order and can't use ORDER BY

Comment: There is no *natural order*. Rows are unordered, unless a column is explicitly given to order them.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

No.  Subqueries are not allowed.

Further, there is no such thing as "natural" order in a SQL table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Your best bet is to do a reverse sort and start at the 11th row:

```
select s.*
from contabilidad.emp001_series s
order by id desc
limit 999999999 offset 10;
```

If you want an arbitrary set of ids, you could also use:

```
select s.*
from contabilidad.emp001_series s
where id < (select s2.id
            from contabilidad.emp001_series s2
            order by s2.id desc
            limit 1 offset 10
           );
```

Both of these assume you have a column of some sort that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice. What I'm trying to do is simulate a paging and get the last page of a table in a single query. I can make a previous query to know the COUNT(*) and then apply it to SELECT `SET @rowsxpage=10;
SET @bottom=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contabilidad.emp001_series);
SET @firstoflastpage=@bottom-@rowsxpage;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM emp001_series LIMIT ?,?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @firstoflastpage,@bottom;`

Comment: If you want to simulate paging then you need an `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html has detailed documentation about MySQL's `SELECT` statement including all its clauses.

It says:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
> by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
> which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
> exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ?
>   placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Expressions, including subqueries, are not mentioned as legal argument in the LIMIT clause.

A simple solution would be to do your task in two queries: the first to get the COUNT() and then use that value as a constant value in the second query that includes the LIMIT.

Not every task needs to be done in a single SQL statement.